# Looking for a query to compare three tables

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I've 3 tables as below in my database.

```
Table 1:
 A
 B
 C
 D

Table 2:
 B
 D
 E
 F

Table 3:
 A
 B
 E
 G
```

I'm looking for a query where table 1 compares with table 2 and table 3 and gives the result as yes or no.

For example: In Table 1 we have '`A`' and in Table 2 we don't have '`A`' but '`A`' is there in table 3 so the result will be '`No`'

But in Table 1 we have '`B`' and in Table 2 we have '`B`' and '`B`' is in table 3 as well so the result will be '`Yes`'.

Regards,
Vikas

Comment: Are you comparing 1 to 2 and 3, or all to all (i.e. should the results include `G` `No`)?

Comment: comparing 1 to 2 and 3.

Comment: This is not very clear what you want to do. This is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ But as a guess you might like into FULL OUTER JOIN.

Comment: [Outer join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/outer-joins) 1 to 2 and 3.  You can then use a [case expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql) to test for matches.  When 2 and 3 don't match they will equal null.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
DECLARE @Tab_1 TABLE(
ID VARCHAR(1)
)

INSERT INTO @Tab_1 VALUES ('A'), ('B'), ('C'), ('D')

DECLARE @Tab_2 TABLE(
ID VARCHAR(1)
)

INSERT INTO @Tab_2 VALUES ('E'), ('B'), ('F'), ('D')

DECLARE @Tab_3 TABLE(
ID VARCHAR(1)
)

INSERT INTO @Tab_3 VALUES ('A'), ('B'), ('E'), ('G')

;WITH cte AS(
SELECT  ISNULL(t1.ID,'X') t1_ID,
        ISNULL(t2.ID,'Y') t2_ID,
        ISNULL(t3.ID,'Z') t3_ID
  FROM @Tab_1 t1
  FULL OUTER JOIN @Tab_2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
  FULL OUTER JOIN @Tab_3 t3 ON t1.ID = t3.ID
)
SELECT  t1_ID,
        t2_ID,
        t3_ID,
        CASE WHEN t1_ID = t2_ID AND t1_ID = t3_ID THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS Result
  FROM cte
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 select colm1,case when count(*) = 3 then 'Yes' else 'No' end Result
 from
 (SELECT distinct colm1 FROM TAB1
  union all
  SELECT distinct colm2 FROM TAB2
  union all
  SELECT distinct colm3 FROM TAB3)a group by colm1
```

Answer (score 0):

One alternative option is create a function. Example

```
     ----Source

    CREATE TABLE ONE ( Let VARCHAR(10) )
    INSERT  INTO ONE
    VALUES  ( 'A' ),
            ( 'B' ),
            ( 'C' ),
            ( 'D' )
    GO
    CREATE TABLE TWO ( LET VARCHAR(10) )
    INSERT  INTO TWO
    VALUES  ( 'B' ),
            ( 'D' ),
            ( 'E' ),
            ( 'F' )
    GO
    CREATE TABLE THREE ( Let VARCHAR(10) )
    INSERT  INTO THREE
    VALUES  ( 'A' ),
            ( 'B' ),
            ( 'E' ),
            ( 'G' )
    GO


    ----Function

    CREATE FUNCTION isCompare ( @let VARCHAR(10) )
    RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
    AS
        BEGIN

            IF ( EXISTS ( SELECT    1
                          FROM      TWO
                          WHERE     let = @let )
                 AND EXISTS ( SELECT    1
                              FROM      THREE
                              WHERE     let = @let )
               )
                BEGIN
                    RETURN 'YES'
                END

            RETURN 'NO'
        END
    GO

  ----Query

    SELECT  dbo.isCompare(let) RESULT
    FROM    ONE 
    GO

 --- End Query

    DROP TABLE ONE
    DROP TABLE TWO
    DROP TABLE THREE
    DROP FUNCTION isCompare
    GO
```

Result:

```
    RESULT
    ----------
    NO
    YES
    NO
    NO

    (4 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that we have three tables as below:

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE (id CHAR)
INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES('a'),('b'),('c'),('d')

DECLARE @t2 TABLE (id CHAR)
INSERT INTO @t2 VALUES('b'),('d'),('e'),('f')

DECLARE @t3 TABLE (id CHAR)
INSERT INTO @t3 VALUES('a'),('b'),('e'),('g')
```

We can simple use `LEFT JOIN` to solve the problem as below:

```
SELECT
    t1.id, 
    t2.id, 
    t3.id, 
    CASE WHEN t1.id IS NULL OR t2.id IS NULL OR t3.id IS NULL THEN 'NO'
         ELSE 'Yes' 
    END AS Msg
FROM @t1 as t1 
     LEFT JOIN @t2 AS t2 ON t1.id=t2.id
     LEFT JOIN @t3 AS t3 ON t2.id=t3.id
```